# How to edit Folder Permissions using GUI?

Tags: windows-8.1, permissions, gui, editing, windows-10-preview

Both on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 TP - x64 Uefi I can't edit folder permissions by using the 'Advanced Security Settings' dialog. It says:

> To modify a permission entry, select the entry and click Edit (if
>   available).

But the 'Edit' button is **always** unavailable. Snip shot:

[image: Big mystery]

Any ideas how to enable this mysterious button?

Comment: Are you logged in as the owner of the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions of folder are usually inherited from its parent (G:\ in your case).

You have to remove this inheritance in order to edit them. Just click to *"Disable inheritance"* button and then *"Copy inherited permissions into explicit permissions on this object"* button in dialog that will appear.

Comment: Can you explain this behavior? Why I can't edit the permissions of the folder when they are inherited?

Comment: There are two _kinds_ of permissions: explicit or inherited. Explicit permissions are set directly for given object (folder). Inherited permissions are _propagated_ from parent object (it is kind of link). So you cannot change them directly on child. Though you can change permissions of parent folder and it will be effectively applied to its childs as well.